# convert 2D array into 1D array using np.newaxis

Tags: python

I am trying to convert 2D array with one column into 1D vector using np.newaxis. The result I got so far is 3D array instead of 1D vector or 1D array.

The 2D array y1 is:

```
y1.shape
(506, 1)

y1
array([[0.42      ],
       [0.36666667],
       [0.66      ],
       [0.63333333],
       [0.69333333],
       ... ])
```

Now I'd like to convert it into 1D array

```
import numpy as np
y2=y1[np.newaxis,:]
y2.shape
(1, 506, 1)
```

You can see after using np.newaxis, the shape of y2 become a 3D array, I am expecting the shape of (506,) 1D array.

what is the problem of my above code? Thanks

Comment: Why do you expect that adding a new axis will reduce the dimensionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.newaxis` expand dimension so 2D -> 3D. If you want to reduce your dimension 2D -> 1D, use `squeeze`:

```
>>> a
array([[0.42      ],
       [0.36666667],
       [0.66      ],
       [0.63333333],
       [0.69333333]])

>>> a.shape()
(5, 1)

>>> a.squeeze()
array([0.42      , 0.36666667, 0.66      , 0.63333333, 0.69333333])

>>> a.squeeze().shape
(5,)
```

From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> Each newaxis object in the selection tuple serves to expand the dimensions of the resulting selection by one unit-length dimension. The added dimension is the position of the newaxis object in the selection tuple.

Answer (score 2):

`np.newaxis()` is used to increase the dimension of the array. It will not decrease the dimension. In order to decrease the dimension, you can use:
`reshape()`

```
y1 = np.array(y1).reshape(-1,)

print(y1.shape)
>>> (506,)
```